# Coefficient Inequalities for Univalent Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Take a function $f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{C}$ that is one-to-one and holomorphic. In addition, take $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Then $$f(z)=z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots.$$ It is known of course that $$|a_k|\leq k$$ for all $k$. I was curious about other inequalities, specifically ones involving polynomials in the coefficients $a_2, a_3, \ldots$. For example, one may show that $$|a_2^2-a_3|\leq 1.$$ In what context (if it all) has this been studied?

Comment: See _Duren Peter L., Univalent functions (Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften 259), Springer-Verlag Berlin and Heidelberg GmbH & Co. K (1983)_

Comment: Also see "Pommerenke christian, _univalent functions_, 1975", page **20**.

Comment: Thanks! Will do.